# Why setAlpha worked in min sdk 8, but don't work on min sdk 9?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to setAlpha to my rowView but I got an error saying that I need minimum sdk 11.

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
```

Well, I am aware that one of the way to solve this problem is to change my minimum sdk to 11, but I don't want to as I need my minimum sdk to be 8/9.

Funny enough, my friend tried `rowView.setAlpha(-80)` in min sdk 8, target 16, and it worked fine, but it could not run in mine, which is min sdk 9, target 16.

I tried solving the problem with `rowView.getBackground().setAlpha(-80)` but there is no alpha effect.

Can someone tell me why is it working in sdk 8, but not 9? What could have been wrong?

*Update

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.knowledge_main, parent, false);
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
```

Comment: try this ... rowView.getBackground().setAlpha(-80)

Comment: @Sandy09 sorry, typo earlier. I actually tried `rowView.getBackground().setAlpha(-80)` and there is no alpha effect.

Comment: Why are you using negative value? according to the documentation, `Drawable.setAlpha()` param should be from 0 to 255

Answer (score 0):

may be some problem while Inflate, both code are working fine

```
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    mView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    setContentView(mView);
    mView.getBackground().setAlpha(-160);


    View mView2 = (View)((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    mView2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    setContentView(mView2);
    mView2.getBackground().setAlpha(-160);
```

Comment: Hey your code works fine. Thanks. :) It has alpha effects on the background. However, it doesn't achieve what I wanted cause it is just on the background, not the text on it. I've updated my codes above. Would you help me to take a look at it?